# Character.charValue() vs toString in JAVA

Tags: java

What is the difference between `charValue()` and `toString()` methods of class `Character`. Both of them return the same i.e, the character value held by the object of the class character as in following code.

```
public class OtherCharMethods 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Character c1 = 'A';
      Character c2 = 'A';

      System.out.printf(
            "c1 = %s\nc2 = %s\n\n", c1.charValue(), c2.toString());

      if (c1.equals(c2))
      System.out.println("c1 and c2 are equal\n");
      else
      System.out.println("c1 and c2 are not equal\n");
     } 
 } // end class OtherCharMethods
```

Comment: one return a `char` native data type, the other a `String` object. You don't see the difference in `System.out.printf()` because the method converts the `char` into `String`.  there are other cases where the difference is apparent (like equality check)

Comment: [charValue()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Character.java#Character.charValue%28%29), [toString()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Character.java#Character.toString%28%29)

Comment: You will see that they are not the same if you test `c1.toString().equals(c1.charValue())`. It should return false (because a string cannot be equal to a char).

Answer (score 1):

The one method returns a single [char value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#charValue()) (**primitive type**); the other one returns a **[String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toString())** (reference type).

That is all there is to this.

Given your comment: the thing to understand - that returned string will of course contain exactly **one** character; the one that `charValue()` returns to you.

**But**: those are still two different things. As the literals "a" and 'a' also contain one char; but in the end **mean** different things. If you just print the variables to System.out; of course that gives the **same** result. But that doesn't make a char the same as a String.

Comment: but character object cannot hold a string. So the returned value will always be a character in this specific case? output will be the same!!

Answer (score 0):

`Character#charValue()` [returns a char](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#charValue--), `Character#toString()` returns an string OBJECT, that is a huge difference between those two, one is a primitive, the other an object

Answer (score 0):

charValue() will represent certain value of the character and toString() function will convert the value into string. so both the operation are different.. if you try to give more than one character in the charvalue() function's object, it will give a compile time error but in toString() case its different you can pass any kind of object and any number of characters which capable to convert it to string.